# Convert enum underlying value to string without knowing the enum type

Tags: c#, enums

I have a method taking an object and returning it in string format with some stuff depending on the type. For example:

```
ConvertObjectToSQL(1); // "1"
ConvertObjectToSQL("Foo"); // "'Foo'"
ConvertObjectToSQL(DateTime.Now); // "'2017/02/22 00:00:00'"
```

My problem occurs when I provide an enum to that method. I want my method to act as if I provided it the enum underlying type. Of course, my method is called in a context where I can't possibly know the enum type.

In the first place, here is what I did:

```
private string ConvertObjectToSQL(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return "NULL";
    }
    else if (obj is DateTime)
    {
        return "'" + obj.ToString() + "'";
    }
    else if (obj is string)
    {
        return "'" + obj.ToString().Replace("'", "''") + "'";
    }

    return obj.ToString();
}
```

But if my enum is:

```
enum FooEnum : int { Foo = 0, Bar = 1 }
```

If want :

```
ConvertObjectToSQL(FooEnum.Foo); // "0"
ConvertObjectToSQL(FooEnum.Bar); // "1"
```

But it actually returns:

```
ConvertObjectToSQL(FooEnum.Foo); // "Foo"
ConvertObjectToSQL(FooEnum.Bar); // "Bar"
```

So I end up with a new else if doing the job:

```
else if (obj is Enum)
{
    var baseType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(obj.GetType());
    return Convert.ChangeType(obj, baseType).ToString();
}
```

My question is: can I avoid reflexion here? Because this methods is called a lots of times.

Comment: try `ConvertObjectToSQL(((int)FooEnum.Foo).toString())`

Comment: @Luminous_Dev: that may not do what is desired if the enum isn't based on `int`...

Comment: @Luminous_Dev: as I said: `my method is called in a context where I can't possibly know the enum type`. So as said @Chris, the enum is not necessarily based on int.

Comment: I have to point out a question here though that you should probably not do some of this at all, you're seemingly constructing SQL by concatenating pieces, you may want to look into using parameters instead.

Comment: You mean you want to avoid the `obj.GetType()` call?

Comment: Are you going to be calling the same method for the same enum lots of times or are your "lots of times" mostly different enums?

Comment: @Magnus: this call and even the Enum.GetUnderlyingType (which I suppose uses reflexion under the hood) call if it is possible yes.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: Mostly the same enums (let's say 4 to 5 different enums). Concerning your other comment, I know I am not doing a clean work here, but the data I am inserting are safe (not retrieved from a form ^^). I will look into a solution involving parameters but I am not sure I can apply it to my situation.

Comment: Can the user who downvotes my question explains why please ?

Comment: Since you only seem to want the number in string format, can't you just do `enumValue.ToString("D")`? This will give you the numeric value in string form without any type conversion or knowledge of the underlying type.

Comment: You can always craft delegates and cache these depending on type, this seems to be slightly faster, not by much, but slightly.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 `.ToString(string format)` is not an overload available through `object`, but I would assume one can cast to `IFormattable`.

Comment: Use ((Enum)obj).ToString("d") when obj is Enum instead of getting underlined type.

Comment: Well if he's casting to Enum it should be available, no? I'm on my phone so limited in what I can check

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 You're right, so that seems like a viable solution.

Comment: Regarding my earlier comment about parameters, if you try to give the parameter the enum directly as a value, have you checked if it converts to number itself?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen If I have the time to test, I will let you now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `enums` implement `IConvertable` we can convert it to a `Decimal` (which will cover the size all integral types) and then to a `string`.

```
private string ConvertObjectToSQL(object obj)
{
    if(obj is Enum)
    {
        return Convert.ToDecimal(obj).ToString();
        //return ((Enum)obj).ToString("D"); Or this
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: That won't work because I do not know the base type of the enum. In my example, I choose int but it could be `char` for example

Comment: Is it legal in IL to have an enum based on `char`? C# only allows the numeric integral types.

Comment: Do you want an numeric value back?

Comment: He has already said what he want, he want the numeric value as a string, no matter which underlying type is used for the int, and an int can be based on byte, sbyte, and so on, in which case the cast to `(int)` will fail.

Comment: @fharreau an enum can not be of type char. _Every enumeration type has an underlying type, which can be any integral type except char_

Comment: Why not just use the enum string format specifier "D"?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 even better

Comment: `String.Format("{0:D}", obj);` also works. Since it does not involve casting (it even does not required a condition on the enum type), is it more efficient ? (in duration of execution)

Comment: @fharreau Its going to cast obj to `IFormattable` and then run `ToString(..)` so I dont except the performance to be different.

Comment: @Magnus Thanks ! At least, it is quicker to write :D.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a delegate to get the underlying type value and cache it.

```
''' <summary>
''' Caches an enum underlying value getter delegate.
''' </summary>
''' <typeparam name="TEnum">Enum type</typeparam>
Public Class CachedEnumUnderlyingValueAccess(Of TEnum)
    Private Shared underlyingTypeValueGetter As Func(Of TEnum, Object) = CreateUnderlyingTypeValueGetter()

    Private Shared Function CreateUnderlyingTypeValueGetter()
        Dim enumUnderlyingType As Type = [Enum].GetUnderlyingType(GetType(TEnum))
        Dim enumParameter As ParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(GetType(TEnum))
        'Convert the enum parameter to its underlying type, then convert it to an Object
        Dim conversionExpression As Expression(Of Func(Of TEnum, Object)) = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Convert(Expression.Convert(enumParameter, enumUnderlyingType), GetType(Object)), enumParameter)
        Return conversionExpression.Compile()
    End Function

    Public Shared Function GetEnumUnderlyingValue(val As TEnum) As Object
        Return underlyingTypeValueGetter.Invoke(val)
    End Function
End Class
```